# Nest can't resolve dependencies of the UserService

Tags: javascript, nest, nestjs

I´m having this error

```
Nest can't resolve dependencies of the UserService (?, SettingsService). Please make sure that the argument UserModel at index [0] is available in the AuthModule context.

    Potential solutions:
    - If UserModel is a provider, is it part of the current AuthModule?
    - If UserModel is exported from a separate @Module, is that module imported within AuthModule?
      @Module({
        imports: [ /* the Module containing UserModel */ ]
      })
```

**auth.module.ts**

```
@Module({
  imports: [
    PassportModule.register({ defaultStrategy: 'jwt' }),
    JwtModule.register({
      secretOrPrivateKey: config.auth.secret,
      signOptions: {
        expiresIn: config.auth.expiresIn,
      },
    }),
    UserModule,
    SettingsModule,
  ],
  controllers: [AuthController],
  providers: [
    AuthService,
    JwtStrategy,
    LocalStrategy,
    UserService,
    SettingsService,
    Logger,
    ... other services,
  ],
  exports: [PassportModule, AuthService],
})
export class AuthModule {}
```

**user.module.ts**

```
@Module({
  imports: [
    MongooseModule.forFeature([{ name: 'User', schema: UserSchema }]),
    SettingsModule,
  ],
  controllers: [UserController],
  providers: [UserService],
  exports: [UserService],
})
export class UserModule {}
```

**app.module.ts**

```
@Module({
  imports: [
    AuthModule,
    UserModule,
    SettingsModule,
    MongooseModule.forRoot(config.db.url),
    WinstonModule.forRoot({
      level: config.logger.debug.level,
    }),
  ],
  controllers: [AppController],
  providers: [AppService],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

**user.service.ts**

```
@Injectable()
export class UserService {
  constructor(@InjectModel('User') private readonly userModel: Model<User>,
              private readonly settingsService: SettingsService) {}

  public async create(user: any): Promise<UserDto> {
    ...
  }
```

I tried everything and can't find the issue, everything seems correct, i even checked every google page results to try to find it but i'm stuck.
The error tells me that i need to import UserModel into AuthModule, but it's already there, i tried to delete every single user model, or the AuthModule and mix them into everything and it still doesnt work, i know i have to export UserService to AuthModule, but can't find the correct way.

Comment: Can you post your `UserService` class ?

Comment: @Nicolas i updated my question with part of the file, the functions are just comon crud operations.

Comment: What's the constructor of your `AuthService` look like? Standard DI syntax: `constructor(private readonly userService: UserService, private readonly settingsService: SettingsService){}`?

Comment: That's right, i have it just like you posted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are providing the `UserService` in your `AuthModule`. However, it should only be in your `UserModule`. In the `AuthModule`, the `UserModel` is unknown.

Comment: I commented UserService and SettingsService and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

Double-check your module imports:

```
@Module({
  imports: [
    MongooseModule.forFeature([
       { name: 'User', schema: UserSchema }
    ]),
    ...
  ],
  ...
})
export class XModule {}
```

And look for silly mistakes! because even if you pass schema and schema name instead of each other, there will be no type errors! The general `Nest can't resolve dependencies` will be all you get for so many mistakes that are probable here...